# Timer and TimerTask with scheduleAtFixedRate causes CalledFromWrongThreadException crash when updating TextView

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm new to Android programming. Right now, I want to update a `TextView` value in an `Activity` at a specified interval.

Car class:

```
public class Car {
    public int Speed;
    public int RPM;
    public int Distance;
    public int Fuel;

    public Car(int Speed, int RPM, int Distance, int Fuel) {
        System.out.println(
                "Inisialisasi Baru"+
                    "\nSpeed: "+ Speed +
                    "\nRPM: "+ RPM +
                    "\nDistance: "+ Distance +
                    "\nFuel: "+ Fuel
        );
        this.Speed = Speed;
        this.RPM = RPM;
        this.Distance = Distance;
        this.Fuel = Fuel;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return Speed;
    }
    public int getRPM() {
        return RPM;
    }
    public int getDistance() {
        return Distance;
    }
    public int getFuel() {
        return Fuel;
    }
}
```

Activity java:

```
TextView carSpeed, carRPM, carDistance, carFuel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mock);

    carSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.carSpeed);
    carRPM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.carRPM);
    carDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.carDistance);
    carFuel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.carFuel);

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        Car car = new Car(20, 20, 20, 5);
        @Override
        public void run(){
            int maxSpeed = car.Speed + 5;
            int minSpeed = car.Speed - 4;
            int maxRPM = car.RPM + 5;
            int minRPM = car.RPM - 4;
            car.Speed = new Random().nextInt((maxSpeed - minSpeed) + 1) + minSpeed;
            car.RPM = new Random().nextInt((maxRPM - minRPM) + 1) + minRPM;
            car.Distance += 1;
            car.Fuel -= 1;
            if (car.Fuel <= 0) {
                car.Fuel += 20;
            }
            if (car.Speed <= 0) {
                car.Speed = 20;
            } else if (car.Speed >= 150) {
                car.Speed -= 50;
            }
            carSpeed.setText(Integer.toString(car.getSpeed()) + " km/h");
            carRPM.setText(Integer.toString(car.getRPM()) + " rpm");
            carDistance.setText(Integer.toString(car.getDistance()) + " km");
            carFuel.setText(Integer.toString(car.getFuel()) + " l");
        }
    },0,5000);
}
```

I think the problem happens because I'm trying to `setText` inside new `Timer()` and this cause application close. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post stack trace?

Comment: @Firda Did Elletlar's answer help you or you are still facing issues? If yes, please accept the answer. If not, please comment what's still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your intuition is correct. The problem happens because the views are being updated from the timer.

The error will be similar to this:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

In Android, views can only be updated from the "UI thread" also commonly known as the "Main Thread".

The problem here is that the Runnable's run() method is being executed in a separate thread.

The updates can be done on the main thread from an Activity like this:

```
...
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        // Do all your view updates in here
        textView.setText("string");
    }
});
....
```

I cannot see the context of your code, but if it is a fragment:
`getActivity().runOnUiThread(...);`

There are also other methods for switching to the main thread. You may want to investigate AsyncTask and Handlers as well.